# React native expo implementing Apple App Tracking Transparency (ATT) for iOS 14.5

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

What is the best way of implementing the Apple App Transparency Tracker (ATT) feature on react native expo? My app keeps getting rejected by apple even after I add:

app.json file :

```
"infoPlist": {
  "NSUserTrackingUsageDescription": "App requires permission...."
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On iOS 14 Apple introduced the App Tracking Transparency permission to access IDFA.
You need to prompt the user whether it allows your app to use libraries that track them or not, adding it on infoPlist just allows you to use this API within your application.

Expo doesn't have this feature yet, but some libraries you can use to prompt the permission

Example: https://docs.expo.io/versions/v41.0.0/sdk/facebook/#facebookgetpermissionsasync

You can use other libraries , such as https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-tracking-transparency

where you can request the App tracking like

```
    import { getTrackingStatus } from 'react-native-tracking-transparency';

    const trackingStatus = await getTrackingStatus();
    if (trackingStatus === 'authorized' || trackingStatus === 'unavailable') {
      // enable tracking features
    }


    import { requestTrackingPermission } from 'react-native-tracking-transparency';
    
    const trackingStatus = await requestTrackingPermission();
    if (trackingStatus === 'authorized' || trackingStatus === 'unavailable') {
      // enable tracking features
    }
```

This might need an update in a near future, as expo releases a new SDK version with a solution for that.

***EDIT***

From Expo 44+

Expo now have a library for TrackTransparency: (https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/tracking-transparency/)

```
expo install expo-tracking-transparency
```

For bare applications: https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/main/packages/expo-tracking-transparency#installation-in-bare-react-native-projects

You can add it as a plugin at your `app.json`

```
{
  "expo": {
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-tracking-transparency",
        {
          "userTrackingPermission": "This identifier will be used to deliver personalized ads to you."
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

And now you can use like this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { requestTrackingPermissionsAsync } from 'expo-tracking-transparency';

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await requestTrackingPermissionsAsync();
      if (status === 'granted') {
        console.log('Yay! I have user permission to track data');
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Tracking Transparency Module Example</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this Lucas, I have tried it and sadly it only works if you eject from Expo

Comment: Hi @Nyasha, I have a managed Expo, and the Facebook solution worked for me.

Comment: Is this message supposed to be in the beginning of the app or when a user first logs in with FB ?  also does requesting access with ```requestTrackingPermission ``` cover the facebook guidelines and make sure there is no tracking even when the user decides to not allow tracking ? @LucasOliveira

Comment: This message needs to be prompted whether your app opens, otherwise, Apple will reject your new binary. I do not use FB login, so I'm not aware if you need to do it before the user logs in using FB accounts. When user reject tracking is your responsibility to make sure your app is not calling FB libraries which tracks the user (advertisement for example). To be honest, if you use this library you would be safe using Facebook.setAdvertiserTrackingEnabledAsync(enabled: boolean): Promise<boolean> for example.

Comment: Apple still rejects my app, do you happen to know why @LucasOliveira? I did exactly what you wrote here

Comment: Hi @OrNakash , I don't know why they rejected you. I have this app tracking on my app and never had any problem. Do they explained why?

Answer (score 2):

You need to request Tracking permissions first (I used react-native-permissions):

```js
import { request, RESULTS, PERMISSIONS } from 'react-native-permissions'

export const requestPermissionTransparency = async () => {
  return await request(PERMISSIONS.IOS.APP_TRACKING_TRANSPARENCY)
}

useEffect(() => {
    ;(async () => {
      const result = await requestPermissionTransparency()
      if (result === RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        //You need to enable analytics (fb,google,etc...)
        await firebase.analytics().setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true)
        console.log('Firebase Analytics: ENABLED')
      }
    })()
  }, [])
```

Remember to add this file in the root project:

```json
// <project-root>/firebase.json
{
  "react-native": {
    "analytics_auto_collection_enabled": false
  }
}
```

References: https://rnfirebase.io/analytics/usage

Answer (score 1):

The solution I ended up using from expo was using the `Facebook.getPermissionsAsync()`

https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/expo-permissions-add-support-to-apptrackingtransparency-permission-on-ios

Answer (score 1):

## **Expo 41+**

TrackingTransparency:
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/tracking-transparency/

```
import { requestTrackingPermissionsAsync } from 'expo-tracking-transparency';
const { status } = await requestTrackingPermissionsAsync();
if (status === 'granted') // do something
```

## **Expo 40 and below**

Admob: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/admob/

```
import { requestPermissionsAsync } from 'expo-ads-admob'
const { status } = await requestPermissionsAsync()
if (status === 'granted') // do something
```